# How to change sync settings through Android API?

Tags: android

Is there a way to change the sync settings of a Gmail account programmatically with an Android app?  For instance, I'd like to enable/disable syncing of a Gmail account from my app, without the user having to do anything.

I took a look at [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html), but that doesn't seem to be the right place to look.

Answer (score 4):

You can change it through the API using `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(Account account, String authority, boolean sync)`.  You need to get a handle to the account in question (usually through the AccountManager class...) and you'll need to lookup the content authority string.  The latter you can get from `android.Provider.xxxContract` (ContactsContract for example...)

Comment: You can see how to get authority in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135447/how-to-check-for-sync-settings-in-android

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you:

- Generally, sync is controlled via the `BACKGROUND_DATA` setting in `Settings.Secure`, which cannot be modified by applications
- The Gmail application is not part of the SDK and so exposes no APIs

Comment: Hm, so the only way to turn syncing on/off is by having the user manually do it?