# How to check for sync settings in android

Tags: android, synchronization

I am building an android app for which I need to check the sync setting of each individual account registered in the device. I know that I can do it through ContentResolver class but I am having some problem with it. I've managed to get the list of all accounts on the device but I don't know where to get the relevant authority of a specific account at run time. Below is the code:

```
AccountManager acm = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    Account[] acct = acm.getAccounts();
    for(int i=0;i<acct.length;i++){
        int p = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(acct[i], null);
        Log.i(TAG,"account name is"+acct[i].name);
        Log.i(TAG,"answer to syncable is: "+String.valueOf(p));
```

The getIsSyncable(Account am,String authority) asks for an account and an authority. As you can see I am passing in NULL instead of the actual authority. Does anyone know of a way I can find the authority to the relevant account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the known SyncAdapters and then query the `ContentResolver`

```
AccountManager acm
        = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
    Account[] acct = null;

    SyncAdapterType[] types = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes();
    for (SyncAdapterType type : types) {
      Log.d(TAG, "--------------------");
      Log.d(TAG, type.authority + "--" + type.accountType);
      acct = acm.getAccountsByType(type.accountType);
      for (int i = 0; i < acct.length; i++) {
        int p = ContentResolver.getIsSyncable(acct[i], type.authority);
        Log.i(TAG, "account name: " + acct[i].name);
        Log.i(TAG, "syncable: " + String.valueOf(p));
      }
    }
```

Output:

11-15 17:12:51.899: DEBUG/syncsample(4572):
 com.google.android.music.MusicContent--com.google 11-15 17:12:51.899:

INFO/syncsample(4572): account name: xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com 11-15
 17:12:51.899: INFO/syncsample(4572): syncable: 1 11-15 17:12:51.899:

INFO/syncsample(4572): account name: xxxxxx@google.com 11-15
 17:12:51.899: INFO/syncsample(4572): syncable: 0

Comment: That's perfect!
Actually I managed to whip up my own solution that involved something similar but I get the authorities from PackageInfo class. However, your solution is much better and neat!

Comment: Just do not miss that is order to get enabled/disabled as in Android settings menu you need to call `getSyncAutomatically`, not `getIsSyncable`.

Answer (score 0):

As there are so many settings in particular account so you have to give the authority of each individual account's specific component.

Like for Contacts  you can give like `ContactsContract.AUTHORITY` which is nothing but com.android.contacts so for other component you can find it from the package name and give it.

Comment: Yeah, but how would I know that at RUN TIME. Assuming that my application would have to run on different devices with differently installed applications. Where can I get the exact authority of each of their accounts for the getIsSyncable function?

Comment: Not possible AFAIK, since third party application has different components added

Comment: That was my conclusion as well, but then is there no way we can get the current sync settings of an account at all in android at run time? This is sad! :(

Comment: We can get the Master sync setting, but not for individual account's components